# Wordpress Stylesheet Not Updating

Tags: css, wordpress

I have a client webpage at http://bit.ly/SV663B, and I'm that close to completing the style changes I was told to make. However, for some reason, the changes I made to the stylesheet was NOT updated no matter how many times I uploaded the css via FTP.

The stylesheet in question is http://www.antalvig.com/m7/wp-content/themes/felis/css/shortcodes.css. When I open up Firebug and check the stylesheet, it seems that there is a ?ver=3.4.2 behind, and I checked umpteen times and the code I've added in wasn't detected. At first I thought it was the cache, but it's been about 7 hours since I checked, and my code is still not updated. Now the weirdest thing is that when I changed http://www.antalvig.com/m7/wp-content/themes/felis/css/style.css and uploaded it, the change is reflected immediately.

I'm guessing the problem lies in the ?ver=3.4.2, but of course that doesn't explain why style.css is updated immediately. I'm really at a loss as to how to update this last css change. Can anyone please help and give me some sort of advice? Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It might not just be your browser cache. Do you have any caching plugins in use?

Comment: My guess is either a caching plugin or some crazy stuff in `.htaccess`

Comment: It's most likely not caching plugin - the plugins that are installed are Custom Contact Forms, Enhanced Admin Bar, Limit Login Attempts and 2 backup plugins. Ain't htaccess either: here's what in it: `AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /m7/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /m7/index.php [L]
</IfModule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys,

I'm sorry - it turns out I had this comma in front of the braces, like `.class, .someclass, .class2, {color:pink;}` and that's why it didn't get picked up by the browser. Must have left it there when copy pasting.

Lesson Learned: NEVER work on your project when you're losing focus (late at night when I did the above), you're gonna screw up somewhere and then spend hours later wondering what happened.

Thanks everyone for your reply though - cheers.

Comment: Glad you got it all worked out. I wouldn't have guessed that the problem was malformed CSS, so good on you for figuring it out. Feel free to mark your question as answered in case other users might have the same question you did.